# Unable to add calendar event with old date via Office 365 REST API

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

It appears as though there is some sort of limitation in the Office 365 REST API that prevents adding events with older dates, but I am unable to nail down the specific constraint. For example, the following JSON payload causes the request to fail with a 400 response:

```
{
    "Subject":"Task/Other",
    "Location":{},
    "Body": {
        "ContentType":"Text",
        "Content":"Appointment text"
    },
    "Start": {
        "DateTime":"1983-05-12T19:00:00",
        "TimeZone":"America/New_York"
    },
    "End": {
        "DateTime":"1983-05-12T19:30:00",
        "TimeZone":"America/New_York"
    }
}
```

However, the following payload succeeds:

```
{
    "Subject":"Task/Other",
    "Location":{},
    "Body": {
        "ContentType":"Text",
        "Content":"Appointment text"
    },
    "Start": {
        "DateTime":"2016-05-12T19:00:00",
        "TimeZone":"America/New_York"
    },
    "End": {
        "DateTime":"2016-05-12T19:30:00",
        "TimeZone":"America/New_York"
    }
}
```

The only difference is the more recent event date. I am unable to find anything in the API documentation about any such constraint. What am I missing?

Comment: Following the sample https://github.com/microsoftgraph/uwp-csharp-snippets-rest-sample, I'm having success creating event at year 1983.

Comment: @Jackie - I am still getting the same vague ErrorPropertyValidationFailure error with Graph as i was with the REST API

Comment: See also https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/datetimetimezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue. However after I change the time zone to UTC, the issue was fixed. As a workaround, I suggest that you convent the time from "America/New_York" to "UTC" first and use the UTC time.

Here is the sample I tested for your reference:

```
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/
authorization: bearer {token}
Content-type: application/json
{
"Subject":"Task/Other",
"Location":{'DisplayName':'Water Cooler'},
"Body": {
    "ContentType":"Text",
    "Content":"Appointment text"
},
"Start": {
    "DateTime":"1983-05-12T19:00:00",
    "TimeZone":"UTC"
},
"End": {
    "DateTime":"1983-05-12T19:30:00",
    "TimeZone":"UTC"
}
}
```

And to fix this issue, you can try to contact the Office Developer team from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).